# Case insensitive Scala parser-combinator

Tags: parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I'm trying to create a [language](https://github.com/systay/cypher), and there are some parts of it that I want to be case insensitive. I'm sure this is something easy, but I haven't been able to find it.

Edit:
Re-reading makes me ashamed of this question. [Here](https://gist.github.com/984483) is a failing test that explains what I mean.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a regular expression instead of a literal.

```
lazy val caseSensitiveKeyword: Parser[String] = "casesensitive"
lazy val caseInsensitiveKeyWord: Parser[String] = """(?i)\Qcaseinsensitive\E""".r
```

(See the docs for [java.util.Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for info on the regex syntax used.)

If you're doing this frequently you could pimp String to simplify the syntax:

```
class MyRichString(str: String) {
  def ignoreCase: Parser[String] = ("""(?i)\Q""" + str + """\E""").r
}

implicit def pimpString(str: String): MyRichString = new MyRichString(str)

lazy val caseInsensitiveKeyword = "caseinsensitive".ignoreCase
```

Comment: Thank you! Works very nicely.